# How to compute Direct and Inverse Conversion between geodetic coordinates (ECEF) to local reference (ENU)

Tags: c, gps, wgs84

How to convert X,Y,Z from local reference (ENU) to world reference (ECEF) and reverse it ??

Input:

```
(lat,long) = center of the local reference system.
       x,y,z = position of the point,in local system reference.
```

Output: (lat,long)= poistion of the point in WGS84.
Also: reverse coordinate.

I suppose the step is:

```
1) convert Xlocal,Ylocal,Zlocal  -> Xecef,Yecef,Zecef

2) convert Xecef,Yecef,Zecef     -> Lat,Long (WGS84)
```

And than

```
1) convert Lat,Long(WGS84)       -> Xecef,Yecef,Zecef

2) convert Xecef,Yecef,Zecef     -> Xlocal,Ylocal,Zlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

The Ordnance Survey has published [A Guide to Coordinate Systems in Great Britain](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf).  It's a PDF document that contains the mathematical algorithms for converting between lat/long and cartesian coordinates.  Obviously it is oriented towards British systems, but the parameters needed for WGS84 are given in the guide.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a geospatial AR app and have just tackled this myself in objective-C / iOS (with quite a bit of help from [this example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple).

The three C functions to convert from lat lon to ecef to ENU and back are below.  The mathematical formulas come from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion) wikipedia article.

```
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees)((M_PI * degrees)/180)

#define WGS84_A (6378137.0)             // WGS 84 semi-major axis constant in meters
#define WGS84_E (8.1819190842622e-2)    // WGS 84 eccentricity

// Converts latitude, longitude to ECEF coordinate system
void latLonToEcef(double lat, double lon, double alt, double *x, double *y, double *z)
{
    double clat = cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lat));
    double slat = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lat));
    double clon = cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lon));
    double slon = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lon));

    double N = WGS84_A / sqrt(1.0 - WGS84_E * WGS84_E * slat * slat);

    *x = (N + alt) * clat * clon;
    *y = (N + alt) * clat * slon;
    *z = (N * (1.0 - WGS84_E * WGS84_E) + alt) * slat;
}

// Converts ECEF to ENU coordinates centered at given lat, lon
void ecefToEnu(double lat, double lon, double xRef, double yRef, double zRef, double xPOI, double yPOI, double zPOI, double *e, double *n, double *u)
{
    double clat = cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lat));
    double slat = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lat));
    double clon = cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lon));
    double slon = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lon));
    double dx = xPOI - xRef;
    double dy = yPOI - yRef;
    double dz = zPOI - zRef;

    *e = -slon * dx  + clon * dy;
    *n = -slat * clon * dx - slat * slon * dy + clat * dz;
    *u = clat * clon * dx + clat * slon * dy + slat * dz;
}
// Converts ENU of a POI (in realtion to a reference point) to ECEF coordinates
void enuToEcef(double lat, double lon, double xRef, double yRef, double zRef, double *xPOI, double *yPOI, double *zPOI, double e, double n, double u)
{
    double clat = cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lat));
    double slat = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lat));
    double clon = cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lon));
    double slon = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(lon));

    *xPOI = (-slon * e) + (-slat * clon * n) + (clat * clon * u) + xRef;
    *yPOI = (clon * e)  + (-slat * slon * n) + (clat * slon * u) + yRef;
    *zPOI = (0 * e)     + (clat * n)         + (slat * u)        + zRef;

}
```